# Galaxy s6 edge does not connect to mobile network when leaving WLAN after upgrade to Android 7

Tags: updates, mobile-network, samsung-galaxy-s-6, t-mobile

My Samsung Galaxy s6 edge does not get internet access via mobile networks when leaving the WLAN area.

After going into offline mode and then online mode again, everything is fine, but until then, there is no way I could use the mobile networks.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have correct APN settings in mobile network settings? Also try resetting to default APN settings. If that fails try changing  network preference settings

Comment: @Xavier_fakerat what is APN ?

Comment: Its Access Point Name found at Settings >> Mobile Networks >> Access Point Names, check if the field has valid information. You may need to get correct settings from your service provider

Comment: @xavier_fakerat okay, I found this. there are two entries for t-mobile, may this be the problem? the information are the same

Comment: just reset to default one, you will need one here. Tap menu reset to default

Comment: @xavier_fakerat okay, now there is only one left. lets see if it works. I will tell you the result tomorrow